Does the Heronian formula for a pyramid frustum also work for a gold bar shape?
Consider a gold bar, with a rectangular base, rectangular top, and the four slant faces (which are trapezoids) slope inwards.
We're given the Length (of base), Width (of base), Height (vertical distance between base and top), and Draft Angle (angle that the slant faces make to the vertical plane).
We can work out the area of the base $B$, and the area of the top $T$, using trigonometry, starting with $L_{top} = L_{base} - 2Htan(A)$ etc.
Is it then valid to compute the volume of the bar using Heron's mean: $V = \frac{H}{3}(B + \sqrt{BT} + T)$ ?
A sample question from my kid's maths exam did this, but I'm not sure , since that formula is valid for a frustum of a rectangular prism; but the general gold bar is not such a frustum because the four slant edges won't meet at a point. (Actually I'm not sure what this shape should be called; it's not a trapezoidal prism as it only has two rectangular faces).

I would think the volume is $\int\limits_0^H(L-2H\tan A)(W-2H\tan A)dH$ $=\int\limits_0^H(LW-2HL\tan A - 2HW\tan A+4H^2\tan^2A) dH$ $=LWH-2(L+W)\tan A\int\limits_0^H HdH+4\tan^2A\int\limits_0^H H^2dH$ $=LWH-2(L+W)\tan A\frac12H^2+4\tan^2A\frac13H^3$

No, not as you describe it, but it would work if the top surface and bottom surface were similar rectangles (or other similar shapes) so the slant edges meet at a point.

@J.W.Tanner would you like to  convert that to an answer? If you can show a counterexample (by getting a different answer there than via Heron's mean) it will answer my question in the negative

Let $H$ be the height of the frustum, $L$ be the length of its base, $W$ be the width of its base, and $A$ be the angle that the slant faces make to the vertical.  As you indicated, the length at height $h$ above the base is $L-2h\tan A$, and the width at height $h$ above the base is $W-2h\tan A$, so the area of the cross-section at height $h$ above the base is $(L-2h\tan A)(W-2h\tan A)$.  The area of the base is $B=LW$, and the area of the top is $T=(L-2H\tan A)(W-2H\tan A).$ The volume of the frustum is obtained by integrating the cross-sectional area from $h=0$ to $H$:
$$V=\int_0^H(L-2h\tan A)(W-2h\tan A)dh=\int_0^H\left(LW-2hL\tan A-2hW\tan A+4h^2\tan^2 A\right)dh$$
$$=LW\int_0^Hdh-2(L+W)\tan A\int_0^Hhdh+4\tan^2A\int_0^Hh^2dh$$
$$=LWH-2(L+W)\tan A\frac12H^2+4\tan^2A\frac13H^3$$
$$=LWH-(L+W)H^2\tan A+\frac43H^3\tan^2A.\tag1$$
If $L=W$, formula ($1$) gives $V=L^2H-2LH^2\tan A+\dfrac43H^3\tan^2A$, which agrees with Heron's formula $V=\dfrac H3(B+\sqrt{BT}+T)=\dfrac H3\left(L^2+L(L-2H\tan A)+(L-2H\tan A)^2\right)$
$=\dfrac H3\left(L^2+L^2-2LH\tan A+L^2-4LH\tan A+4H^2\tan^2 A\right)=\dfrac H3\left(3L^2-6LH\tan A+4H^2\tan^2 A\right).$
But if, say, $L=5, W=20, H=2, $ and $A=45^o$, then $B=100$ and $T=(5-2)(20-2)=54$, so Heron's formula gives $\dfrac23\left(100+10\sqrt{54}+54\right)=\dfrac{308}3+20\sqrt6\approx152$, whereas formula ($1$) gives $200-25\cdot4+\dfrac43\cdot8\approx111$, so Heron's formula does not give the correct answer.
